# json.Decoding a TCP connection and logging the original data at the same time in Go

Tags: json, go, tcp, copy, reader

I'm using a `json.Decoder` to decode a `net.Conn` into a custom struct. I would like to also log the original JSON string sent on the `net.Conn` without modifying it.

I am looking for an efficient way to achieve this. I currently have the following code:

```golang
reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)   // conn is a net.Conn
dec := json.NewDecoder(reader)

for {   

    // How can I also log the original data before decoding it into the struct?

    var dst customStruct
    if err = dec.Decode(&dst); err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("failed to decode message: %s", err)
        break
    }

    // do something with dst...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [iotest.NewReadLogger](https://godoc.org/testing/iotest#NewReadLogger) to log the data as the data is read:

```
prefix := fmt.Sprintf("%p:", conn)
reader := bufio.NewReader(iotest.NewReadLogger(prefix, conn)) 
dec := json.NewDecoder(reader)

for {   

    var dst customStruct
    if err = dec.Decode(&dst); err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("failed to decode message: %s", err)
        break
    }

    // do something with dst...

}
```

If the read logger output does not match your taste, then copy [the implementation](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/78c20c81aaa7d8d8a4aa2132806f51fb68f33a1e/src/testing/iotest/logger.go#L39-L47) and adjust as needed. The implementation is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ioutil.ReadAll()` and then print and decode from the bytes. But since you are reading all of the bytes without using a buffer, you should ideally put this behind a `debug` flag check.

```
bs,err := ioutil.ReadAll()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

log.Printf("output: %s", string(bs))

var dst customStruct
if err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &dst); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Ideally, everything should still be buffered. I have removed the "for debugging purposes" from the original question as it needs to be logged in production as well.